# Is there any upside to terror?

Tags: sunless-sea

A general principle in Sunless Sea seems to be to [minimize your Terror as much as possible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207081/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-terror). But that makes me wonder: Is there any situation in the game where having *more* terror has any advantage? Like any beneficial random events which only happen when you have a minimum of terror? Or any situations which have a more beneficial outcome when you have more terror?

Please use [spoilers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) as appropriate.

Comment: Great title. Hoping for a HNQ entry.

Comment: @Flater Don't get your hopes up. This question is from 9 months ago.

Comment: [Gandalf put his hand on Pippin's head. "There never was much hope, he answered. Just a fool's hope, as I have been told."](http://www.youtube.be/watch?v=Y0S_MebzyzQ)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a 1% random event that occurs when you're sailing with Terror ≥ 75 and with...

> a tattoo. [**An Old Friend**](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/An_Old_Friend) will give you [the Lady in Lilac](http://sunlesssea.gamepedia.com/The_Lady_in_Lilac), a pretty good surgeon (+6 to Hearts, Pages and Mirrors) who also appears in somewhat different circumstances in Fallen London. Unfortunately she disappears when Terror drops below 25, so it's hard to keep her around.

Do remember that there are other, less pleasant random events that can also trigger when your terror reaches 75 and above.

Answer (score 4):

You need Terror ≥ 1 to sleep in your lodgings, which has other benefits than reducing terror.

> Most notable among these is reducing *Menaces: Yearning, Burning* by 2 to 3.

You also need Terror ≥ 70 (and Something Awaits You) to take the *Listen* action in the Iron Republic, which

> gives you 70 fragments, plus one fragment for every two terror over 70.