# Is going slow more efficient than going fast?

Tags: sunless-sea

So I know that the emergency engine power (F) is less efficient than regular travel, i.e. it requires more fuel per distance traveled. Turning on the headlight also requires more fuel than having it off.

However, I can't tell whether or not going at speed 1 is more fuel-efficient than speed 2. For a given distance, speed 2 means fewer supplies used and less terror accrued, but what about fuel? Does it use more fuel or the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Speeds 1 and 2 are equally efficient in a given direction. Going backwards will consume the same amount of fuel per tick as going forwards, but you will be significantly slower.

See also [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/205549/107692) -- note the "Lights Off" data showing that half speed and full speed take you equally far on a single unit of fuel.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, answer is **no**.
Please read this [article](https://steamcommunity.com/app/304650/discussions/0/610573009238054203/), here you have nice example :

> I traveled from Fallen London to Cumaen Canal...[]... Here are the resulting data:
>
> - one engine power = -2 fuel, -4 supply, -9 terror, time for voyage is 5 minutes, 24 seconds
> - two engine power = -2 fuel, -2 supply, -3 terror, time for voyage is 2 minutes, 39 seconds
> - two engine power while pushing full power to engines = -5 fuel, -1 supply, -2 terror, time for voyage is 1 minute, 33 seconds

Comment: Hi Djordje, it's generally encouraged to summarize the content of links in your post. Instead of posts like "Read this article", it would be better to link to the article and then quickly explain the useful parts.

Comment: @Broneironaut thanks for advise, i hope that my answer is better now